# Changing Windows time format from displaying "." to ":"

Tags: windows-10, date-time

Very tedious question, but I simply can't stand the format.

I'd like to change the way time is displayed from eg. 11.26 to 11:26

I can't seem to do this anywhere within the Windows 10 settings, I've searched throughout the whole 
Date & Time settings as well as any Control Panel settings, trying to change Short time and Long time within it, doesn't give me any other options.

How would I go by changing it by other means?

EDIT:
Current Windows build is: 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Comment: Where are you seeing this format, the clock in the bottom right?  What is your Region and Regional format set to be out of interest?

Comment: Mainly bottom right but anywhere within Windows where time is displayed. My region is Denmark and regional format is English (Denmark). Normal time format should be using ":", I recently installed a fresh version of Windows 10 in order to fix some previous errors. Although there the time worked without a problem.

Comment: My Windows 10 install gives me an option for ```11.26.30``` or ```11:26:30```. You can recheck in Settings > Time and Language > Region > Change Data Format in bottom of page.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this. Though I don't get the option to change the time format, I can only choose "11.26.30"

Comment: Can you give me your selected regional format?

Comment: English (Denmark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. You just have to select a compatible regional format. For example, you can simply select English(United States) and your problem is solved.

Comment: What if you're Spanish, or Hungarian, or Chinese… or… anything else that doesn't use a standard English keyboard layout?

Comment: @Tetsujin I do not claim this is a universal solution. I just advised him only after knowing that he is using English. If you are using any other language, refer to the second answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Launch the `Region` settings by running: `Intl.cpl`.
2. Click the `Additional settings...` button.
3. You can then edit the `Time formats` values from `.` to `:` as shown below:

[image: Time format]

Comment: A universal solution ```+1```. But for beginners, my answer is quite enough. :)